How can I start zoomed in on user & in 3D using iOS 17 MapKit?
I want to alter this code so that when the Map is initialised, it starts off more zoomed in on the user's location and the pitch should be in 3D by default. How can I do this? I assume there is a good way to do this for iOS 17.
At the moment the code successfully is positioned over the user's location however I want it much more zoomed in.
The map currently initialises in 2D pitch. I have a  MapPitchToggle() button that makes it go into 3D, however I would like the map to initialise already in 3D. How can I do this?
Here is my code:
struct Home: View {
    
    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .userLocation(fallback: .automatic)
    @State private var visibleRegion: MKCoordinateRegion?
    @State private var searchResults: [MKMapItem] = []
    @State private var selectedResult: MKMapItem?
    @State private var showDetails: Bool = false
    @State private var lookAroundScene: MKLookAroundScene?
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Map(position: $position, selection: $selectedResult) {
            
            let customLocations: [MKMapItem] = [
                createMapItem(name: "Via Palamos", coordinate: .viaPalamos),
                createMapItem(name: "Larry Way", coordinate: .larryWay),
            ]
            
            
            ForEach(customLocations, id: \.self) { result in
                Marker(result.name ?? "Unknown Location", systemImage: "binoculars.fill", coordinate: result.placemark.coordinate)
                    .tint(.blue)
            }
            .annotationTitles(.hidden)
            
            
            UserAnnotation()
            
        }
        .mapStyle(.standard(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll))
        .mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
        .sheet(isPresented: $showDetails, onDismiss: {
            withAnimation(.snappy) {
                
            }
        }, content: {
            MapDetails()
                .presentationDetents([.height(750)])
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .height(750)))
                .presentationCornerRadius(25)
                .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
        })
        .onAppear {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        //MARK: This could help animate it nicely, i think safe inset view is causing interference atm though
        //        .animation(.easeIn)
        .onChange(of: searchResults) {
            position = .automatic
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedResult) { oldValue, newValue in
            /// Displaying Details about the Selected Place
            showDetails = newValue != nil
            /// Fetching Look Around Preview, when ever selection Changes
            fetchLookAroundPreview()
        }
        .onMapCameraChange { context in
            visibleRegion = context.region
        }
        .mapControls {
            VStack {
                MapUserLocationButton()
                //MARK: Can I make it pitch more by defualt? and make it the automaitic mode on initilisation
                MapPitchToggle()
                MapCompass()
                MapScaleView()
            }
            .buttonBorderShape(.circle)
        }
    }
}

